# Setting TCP_NODELAY with java.net.HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, networking

Will it be useful to set TCP_NODELAY in java code while sending HTTP Get requests?
How we can set TCP_NODELAY with `java.net.HttpURLConnection`?